# Is it possible to change a package from a script task that exists in the same package?

Tags: ssis

In SSIS... is it possible to access and change the package itself from one of its script tasks? If it is... could you please provide an example?

For instance, I would like to programmatically configure the tasks within a foreach loop from a script task located outside (before) the loop. Something like reading a file and add/removing/configuring tasks depending on its contents.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible - however, I do something very similar by utilizing a second "child" package that I reuse numerous times. In the script you can simply clear out the child package, put all of the items/containers/constraints you need into it, and then execute it.

Comment: Thx, thats the approach I'm taking.

Answer (score 2):

As @Derek had already mentioned, it is not possible to alter the package itself. However, you can use precedence constraints/Expressions to alter the behavior of Control Flow tasks based on the value present in variable(s), if that is what you meant by altering a package.

Here are few examples where I have used precedence constraints to redirect/**restrict** the control flow tasks based on an expression:

[**How to loop through only files that don't exist in destination using an SSIS package?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598139/how-to-loop-through-only-files-that-dont-exist-in-destination-using-an-ssis-pack/6667014#6667014)

[**How can I stop a package execution based on a stored procedure output?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374376/how-can-i-stop-a-package-execution-based-on-a-stored-procedure-output/6376155#6376155)

[**How to avoid SSIS FTP task from failing when there are no files to download?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140850/how-to-avoid-ssis-ftp-task-from-failing-when-there-are-no-files-to-download/6715972#6715972) `(This example uses a script task followed by a Foreach Loop container.)`

[**How to write an SQL statement output to a CSV file?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374405/ssis-2008-writing-a-sql-statement-to-a-csv-flatfile/6374724#6374724)

Hope that helps.